# Finding element Selenium driver java use xpath on

Tags: java, selenium

Hi i have html code and  use selenium driver for ui tests

```
      <div class = all>
         <div class = "abc">
          <strong> 111 </strong>
           <span> a </span>

           <div class = "abc"> 
             <strong> 222 </strong>
              <span> b</span>
             </div>
           </div>
      </div>
```

and if use

```
 findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='all']")).getText();
```

I get all, but i need only one element only one(111).Help me please

Answer (score 0):

Please try with :

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class*='all'] > div ")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath this should be pretty easy:

```
 findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='abc'][1]")).getText();
```

Comment: yes ! this should be easy but not work  and get exception unable to find element

Comment: <div class = all> Why all here without a quotes?

Comment: sorry it's my mistake <div class ='all'>

Comment: try findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='abc'][1]")).getText();

Comment: Good, I have edited my answer. Please,  mark it is answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class = all>
         <div class = "abc">
          <strong> 111 </strong>
           <span> a </span>

           <div class = "abc"> 
             <strong> 222 </strong>
              <span> b</span>
             </div>
           </div>
      </div>
Answer to get 111
//div[contains(@class,"all")]//span[contains(text,"a")]/preceding-sibling::strong
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below mentioned `xpath`

```
//div[@class='abc']/strong[text()= '111']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `class` attribute of `<div>` tag and move ahead with `<strong>` tag along with `text` method.